# I implementing customer service that has a list of api's for admin and customers

Tags: spring-boot, rest, microservices

if admin wants to see specific customer data ,should i make two api's or make the admin uses the same api for customer to get the resources ? any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Think you should not have different endpoints for Admin and Customer. 
The endpoints should be for a specific application logic and then, you should authorize, who have access to these endpoints.

Eg: Have 2 different roles Admin and Customer.

For this endpoint you can authorize and give access to both Admin and customer

Answer (score 0):

You should have same end point. You need to apply role based access. There are different ways you can achieve that. 
Below is the link where you can use spring boot security to achieve it :-
https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration

You can also use role based access using different methods such as at DB level or your custom frame work depending upon how big your application is or wants to be.